# Inno Setup - Multiple software versions in one installation

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to make a setup with multiple versions of software and i want to make it have the option for portable / install.

I have a customized components page. It should show after info page and then the directory selection page should show once the options are selected. I THINK I have the `[Files]` and `[Tasks]` and `[Components]` sections figured out. It's mainly the code section I am struggling with.

For example if the user selects to install the *Pro* version by using the radio button, once *Next* is clicked it should show the directory selection page and then after continuing it should install or extract (depending on portable or install selections). The installer should install/extract the specified version based on specified files marked as *Pro* (in the `[Files]` and `[Components]` sections).

I have tried lots of variations of code but my current variation is below and it does not work (ignore the `SelectedValueIndex` numbers, I have yet to put the correct value in but I wanted to make sure it would compile first).
I have code for silent switches that i have to link to the radio buttons too but I think that part will work. Its literally just trying to get the selections (radio buttons and check boxes) to work. Also if you select install for one of the versions id like the group box for portable options to be greyed out (un-selectable) and vice versa. At the moment I can't get the radio buttons to have any values they just do nothing.

Simpler explanation:
Lets say there are two versions of an application *Free* and *Pro*.
The files that install depend on whether the user selects *Free* or *Pro*. (Set in the [Files], and [Components] Sections respectively).

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var  SystemMenu: HMENU;
begin
 {Create Mode Selection Page}
    UsagePage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpInfoBefore,
   'Mode', 'Select Installation Mode',
    'Mode',
   True, False);
    UsagePage.Add('FreeInstall');
    UsagePage.Add('BusinessInstall');
    UsagePage.Add('TechnicianInstall');
    UsagePage.Add('ProfessionalInstall');
    UsagePage.Add('FreePortable');
    UsagePage.Add('BusinessPortable');
    UsagePage.Add('TechnicianPortable');
    UsagePage.Add('ProfessionalPortable');
    //
    {Set Default Checkbox - Normal Install}
    if (FreeInstall)
    then
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 1
    else
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;

    if (BusinessInstall)
  then
        // Set the Respective Checkbox on The Wizard.
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 1
    else
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;

    if (TechnicianInstall)
    then
        // Set the Respective Checkbox on The Wizard.
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 1
    else
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;

   if (ProfessionalInstall)
    then
        // Set the Respective Checkbox on The Wizard.
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 1
    else
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;
        
    {Set Default Checkbox - Portable}
    if (FreePortable)
    then
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 1
    else
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;

    if (BusinessPortable)
    then
        // Set the Respective Checkbox on The Wizard.
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 1
    else
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;

    if (TechnicianPortable)
    then
        // Set the Respective Checkbox on The Wizard.
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 1
    else
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;

   if (ProfessionalPortable)
    then
        // Set the Respective Checkbox on The Wizard.
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 1
    else
        UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;
    WizardForm.Caption := '{#MyAppName} v{#MyAppVersion}';
      TotalSpace;
    WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Hide;
```

It won't compile like this

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) to bind `[Files]` section entries to the selection on the custom page:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyProgFree.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: IsModeSelected(0)
Source: "MyProgPro.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: IsModeSelected(1)

[Code]

var
  UsagePage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

function IsModeSelected(Mode: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex = Mode);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  UsagePage :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(
      wpInfoBefore, 'Mode', 'Select Installation Mode', 'Mode', True, False);
  UsagePage.Add('FreeInstall');
  UsagePage.Add('ProInstall');
end;
```